# Changing SQL Agent Job Schedule time programmaticaly doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, jobs, schedule, sql-agent-job

I have an SQL Agent Job, that is supposed to be fired everyday at provided time. If I change the schedule time manualy from Management Studio, it works fine, but i need to change the time using stored procedure as below:

```
update s set
s.active_start_time = @time
from msdb..sysjobs j
left join msdb..sysjobschedules js on j.job_id = js.job_id
left join msdb..sysschedules s on js.schedule_id = s.schedule_id
where j.name = 'MyJobName'
```

And guess what? After running such procedure, when I check scheduled time in Management Studio, it's updated correctly, BUT obviously Job ignores that.

I even found out, that this Job keeps somewhere the old schedule time that was set manually, and run using that one - if I for example manually set time to 10:45 AM, and then quickly change time using procedure to 10:55 AM, even if schedule time inside Management Studio looks to be updated, Job still will run at 10:45...

Any thoughts what can be wrong?

Comment: Dont update the system tables directly use the provided stored procedures to do the work for see this link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187354.aspx

Comment: it really did help, thanks Namphibian!